Approaches for Classifying Scanned Documents with Mixed Printed and Handwritten Text: Exploring LLMs and OCR with ML Integration
What would be the best method for working with scanned document classification when some documents contain a mix of printed and handwritten numbers, such as student report cards? I need to retrieve subjects and compute averages, considering that different students may have different subjects depending on their schools.
The classification will also be domain-specific, hence, I will be collecting the documents and have them labeled and trained. These are the categories student information (students filled it up), certificate of enrolment, medical certificate, and the report cards. I also plan to develop a search functionality for users to retrieve the documents.
I am considering using a Large Language Model (LLM), such as LayoutLM, but I am still uncertain. Alternatively, I could use OCR combined with a machine-learning model for text classification.
Also in: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/1ghrrgr/d_approaches_for_classifying_scanned_documents/
